# How to Convert from List to String from an Array that gets it's stuff from previous activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to convert the specific item on the list after clicking it, it converts to a string, and then sends that information back to the MainActivity. Having trouble converting the information to the string.

```
 namespace GPS2
{
[Activity(Label = "@string/GPSHistory")]
public class GPSHistory : ListActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Create your application here
        // Draw controls
        // SetContentView(Resource.Layout.GPSHistoryLayout);



        var strGPSAnswer = Intent.Extras.GetStringArrayList("Answer") ?? new string[0];
        ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, strGPSAnswer);

        ListView.TextFilterEnabled = true;

        ListView.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args)
        {

            //Confirmation that it works.
            Toast.MakeText(Application, ((TextView)args.View).Text, ToastLength.Short).Show();

            //Prepare string and send back to first page.
            var i = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            i.PutExtra("string", strGPSAnswer);
            StartActivity(i);

        };
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is type of items in this listview? Please share your dataset of listview

Answer (score 0):

As per Android Intent docs  [intent extras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putStringArrayListExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)),
the

> putStringArrayListExtra

name should be like:

> Add extended data to the intent. The name must include a package
>   prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use names like
>   "com.android.contacts.ShowAll"

In your code it looks like **"Answer"** is the key which is not including the package prefix.

*I could have added this in comment, but don't have enough points.*